# How to prove this inequality using AM-GM?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, products, symmetric-polynomials, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Suppose $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers. Then prove that $$\Big(\frac{a+b}{2}\Big)\Big(\frac{b+c}{2}\Big)\Big(\frac{c+a}{2}\Big)\ge\Big(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\Big)\Big(abc\Big)^\frac{2}{3}\tag{*}$$

My approach: From AM-GM $$\Big(\frac{a+b}{2}\Big)\ge\Big(ab\Big)^\frac{1}{2}\tag{1}$$
Similarly, $\Big(\frac{b+c}{2}\Big)\ge\Big(bc\Big)^\frac{1}{2}\tag{2}$ and $\Big(\frac{c+a}{2}\Big)\ge\Big(ca\Big)^\frac{1}{2}\tag{3}$
Multiplying $(1), (2)$ and $(3)$, we get $$\Big(\frac{a+b}{2}\Big)\Big(\frac{b+c}{2}\Big)\Big(\frac{c+a}{2}\Big)\ge\Big(abc\Big)\tag{4}$$
Which can be written as $$\Big(\frac{a+b}{2}\Big)\Big(\frac{b+c}{2}\Big)\Big(\frac{c+a}{2}\Big)\ge\Big(abc\Big)^\frac{2}{3}\Big(abc\Big)^\frac{1}{3}\tag{4*}$$
Now, again from AM-GM $$\Big(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\Big)\ge\Big(abc\Big)^\frac{1}{3}\tag{5}$$
But now I am stuck. What should I do to get to $(*)$ ?

Comment: Hint: Try to show $\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\left(\frac{b+c}{2}\right)\left(\frac{c+a}{2}\right) \ge \left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)\left(\frac{ab+bc+ca}{3}\right)$ by expanding both sides and use AMGM.

Comment: It is interesting to point out that the given inequality is equivalent to 
$$ R^3 r \geq \tfrac{8}{27} \Delta^2 $$ for triangles.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality
$$ \sum_{sym} a^2 b^1 c^0 \geq \sum_{sym} a^1 b^1 c^1 $$
holds by bunching / [Muirhead's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muirhead%27s_inequality) and it is equivalent to
$$ \frac{a+b}{2}\cdot\frac{a+c}{2}\cdot\frac{b+c}{2}\geq \frac{a+b+c}{3}\cdot\frac{ab+ac+bc}{3}.$$
The given inequality is weaker than the latter, since $\frac{ab+ac+bc}{3}\geq\left(abc\right)^{2/3}$ holds by AM-GM.
As pointed out in the comments, the given inequality is equivalent to
$$ R^3 r \geq \tfrac{8}{27}\Delta^2 $$
for triangles.

Comment: I have two questions. What do you mean by 'inequality is weaker' and 'bunching'?

Comment: @Vivek: *bunching* is just a synonym for *application of Muirhead's inequality*. By saying that  $a\geq c$ *is weaker* than $a\geq b$, I mean that $a\geq c$ is just a consequence of $a\geq b$, since $b\geq c$.

Answer (score 1):

By AM-GM: $$\prod_{cyc}(a+b)-\frac{8}{9}(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)=\frac{1}{9}\sum_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c-2abc)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{9}\sum_{cyc}(a^2c+b^2c-2abc)\geq\frac{1}{9}\sum_{cyc}(2\sqrt{a^2c\cdot b^2c}-2abc)=0.$$
Id est, by AM-GM again we obtain:
$$\prod_{cyc}\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)^3=\frac{1}{512}\left(\prod_{cyc}(a+b)\right)^3\geq\frac{1}{512}\cdot\frac{512}{729}(a+b+c)^3(ab+ac+bc)^3\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{1}{27}\left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^3\left(3\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2a^2}\right)^3=\left(\frac{a+b+c}{3}\right)^3a^2b^2c^2$$ and we are done!

Comment: Wow!!! How does your mind work???? I mean, what is your thought process and strategy for something like this?

Comment: @Vivek The strategy is to get an estimation for $(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)$ such that to use $a+b+c$ because $\sqrt[3]{abc}$ we can get always by AM-GM. We see that it turned out.

Comment: And how do you know to start from $(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)-\frac{8}{9}(a+b+c)(ab+ac+bc)$? I could have never thought about that. I want to be like you.

Comment: @Vivek I want to get $(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)\geq (a+b+c)A(a,b,c),$ where $A(a,b,c)$ is symmetric, homogeneous with degree $2$, such that $A(1,1,1)=\frac{8}{3}$ and the inequality would be still true. The easiest $A$ for this role it's $\frac{8}{9}(ab+ac+bc)$ or maybe $\frac{8}{3}\sqrt[3]{a^2b^2c^2}$. There are infinitely many these $A$. But the first is valid.